# Pico container exception: org.picocontainer.injectors.AbstractInjector$UnsatisfiableDependenciesException:?

Tags: java, selenium, cucumber, picocontainer

I seem to be getting a pico container exception: org.picocontainer.injectors.AbstractInjector$UnsatisfiableDependenciesException.

My code is as follows:

Page Object representing a specific page of a website:

```
     public class GooglePage {
        private WebDriver driver;

        private String stringLocator = "edffsfds";

        @FindBy(how = How.XPATH,using = "//div[@id='header']/ul[1]/li[11]/a")
        public WebElement logout;

          public GooglePage(WebDriver driver) {
              this.driver = driver;
              PageFactory.initElements(driver, this);
          }

        public WebElement getLogout() {
            return logout;
        }

        public void setLogout(WebElement logout) {
            this.logout = logout;
        }

        public String getExampleStringLocator() {
            return stringLocator;
        }
    }
```

Steps class:

```
    import CucumberNewExcel.transformer.pageObjects.GooglePage;
    import cucumber.api.java.en.Given;
    import cucumber.api.java.en.When;

    public class GoogleSteps {
        private GooglePage googlePage;

        public GoogleSteps(GooglePage googlePage) {
            this.googlePage = googlePage;
        }   

        @Given("^I access \"([^\"]*)\"$")
        public void i_access(String arg1) throws Throwable {
            //System.out.println("Hello: " + googlePage.getExampleStringLocator());
        }

        @When("^I click on the signin button$")
        public void i_click_on_the_signin_button() throws Throwable {
            //System.out.println("Hello: " + googlePage.getExampleStringLocator());
        }
    }
```

POM Dependencies:

```
<dependencies>
            <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.seleniumhq.selenium/selenium-java -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
                <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
                <version>3.11.0</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>junit</groupId>
                <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
                <version>4.12</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
                <artifactId>cucumber-java</artifactId>
                <version>1.2.5</version>
                <scope>test</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
                <artifactId>cucumber-jvm</artifactId>
                <version>1.2.5</version>
                <type>pom</type>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
                <artifactId>cucumber-junit</artifactId>
                <version>1.2.5</version>
                <scope>test</scope>
            </dependency>


            <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/info.cukes/cucumber-core -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
                <artifactId>cucumber-core</artifactId>
                <version>1.2.5</version>
            </dependency>

            <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/info.cukes/cucumber-html -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
                <artifactId>cucumber-html</artifactId>
                <version>0.2.3</version>
            </dependency>

            <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/info.cukes/cucumber-java -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
                <artifactId>cucumber-java</artifactId>
                <version>1.2.5</version>
            </dependency>

            <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/info.cukes/cucumber-jvm-deps -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
                <artifactId>cucumber-jvm-deps</artifactId>
                <version>1.0.5</version>
            </dependency>

            <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/info.cukes/gherkin -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
                <artifactId>gherkin</artifactId>
                <version>2.12.2</version>
            </dependency>

            <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hamcrest/hamcrest-all -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.hamcrest</groupId>
                <artifactId>hamcrest-all</artifactId>
                <version>1.3</version>
            </dependency>

            <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/info.cukes/cucumber-picocontainer -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
                <artifactId>cucumber-picocontainer</artifactId>
                <version>1.2.5</version>
            </dependency>

            <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/info.cukes/cucumber-testng -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
                <artifactId>cucumber-testng</artifactId>
                <version>1.2.5</version>
            </dependency>

            <!-- Extent Reports -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.aventstack</groupId>
                <artifactId>extentreports</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.5</version>
            </dependency>

            <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.freemarker/freemarker -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.freemarker</groupId>
                <artifactId>freemarker</artifactId>
                <version>2.3.26-incubating</version>
            </dependency>
            <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/net.masterthought/cucumber-reporting -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>net.masterthought</groupId>
                <artifactId>cucumber-reporting</artifactId>
                <version>3.6.0</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.vimalselvam</groupId>
                <artifactId>cucumber-extentsreport</artifactId>
                <version>2.0.4</version>
            </dependency>

            <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/info.cukes/cucumber-jvm-deps -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
                <artifactId>cucumber-jvm-deps</artifactId>
                <version>1.0.5</version>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
```

For some reason when executing my feature file, I seem to be receiving the following exception any ideas?

```
org.picocontainer.injectors.AbstractInjector$UnsatisfiableDependenciesException: CucumberNewExcel.transformer.pageObjects.GooglePage has unsatisfied dependency 'interface org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver' for constructor 'public CucumberNewExcel.transformer.pageObjects.GooglePage(org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver)' from org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer@2f67a4d3:2<|
    at org.picocontainer.injectors.ConstructorInjector.getGreediestSatisfiableConstructor(ConstructorInjector.java:191)
    at org.picocontainer.injectors.ConstructorInjector.getGreediestSatisfiableConstructor(ConstructorInjector.java:110)
    at org.picocontainer.injectors.ConstructorInjector.access$100(ConstructorInjector.java:51)
    at org.picocontainer.injectors.ConstructorInjector$1.run(ConstructorInjector.java:331)
    at org.picocontainer.injectors.AbstractInjector$ThreadLocalCyclicDependencyGuard.observe(AbstractInjector.java:270)
    at org.picocontainer.injectors.ConstructorInjector.getComponentInstance(ConstructorInjector.java:364)
    at org.picocontainer.behaviors.AbstractBehavior.getComponentInstance(AbstractBehavior.java:64)
    at org.picocontainer.behaviors.Stored.getComponentInstance(Stored.java:91)
    at org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer.getInstance(DefaultPicoContainer.java:699)
    at org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer.getComponent(DefaultPicoContainer.java:647)
    at org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer.getComponent(DefaultPicoContainer.java:632)
    at org.picocontainer.parameters.BasicComponentParameter$1.resolveInstance(BasicComponentParameter.java:118)
    at org.picocontainer.parameters.ComponentParameter$1.resolveInstance(ComponentParameter.java:136)
    at org.picocontainer.injectors.SingleMemberInjector.getParameter(SingleMemberInjector.java:78)
    at org.picocontainer.injectors.ConstructorInjector$CtorAndAdapters.getParameterArguments(ConstructorInjector.java:309)
    at org.picocontainer.injectors.ConstructorInjector$1.run(ConstructorInjector.java:335)
    at org.picocontainer.injectors.AbstractInjector$ThreadLocalCyclicDependencyGuard.observe(AbstractInjector.java:270)
    at org.picocontainer.injectors.ConstructorInjector.getComponentInstance(ConstructorInjector.java:364)
    at org.picocontainer.behaviors.AbstractBehavior.getComponentInstance(AbstractBehavior.java:64)
    at org.picocontainer.behaviors.Stored.getComponentInstance(Stored.java:91)
    at org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer.getInstance(DefaultPicoContainer.java:699)
    at org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer.getComponent(DefaultPicoContainer.java:647)
    at org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer.getComponent(DefaultPicoContainer.java:678)
    at cucumber.runtime.java.picocontainer.PicoFactory.getInstance(PicoFactory.java:37)
    at cucumber.runtime.java.JavaStepDefinition.execute(JavaStepDefinition.java:38)
    at cucumber.runtime.StepDefinitionMatch.runStep(StepDefinitionMatch.java:37)
    at cucumber.runtime.Runtime.runStep(Runtime.java:300)
    at cucumber.runtime.model.StepContainer.runStep(StepContainer.java:44)
    at cucumber.runtime.model.StepContainer.runSteps(StepContainer.java:39)
    at cucumber.runtime.model.CucumberScenario.run(CucumberScenario.java:44)
    at cucumber.runtime.junit.ExecutionUnitRunner.run(ExecutionUnitRunner.java:102)
    at cucumber.runtime.junit.FeatureRunner.runChild(FeatureRunner.java:63)
    at cucumber.runtime.junit.FeatureRunner.runChild(FeatureRunner.java:18)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at cucumber.runtime.junit.FeatureRunner.run(FeatureRunner.java:70)
    at cucumber.api.junit.Cucumber.runChild(Cucumber.java:95)
    at cucumber.api.junit.Cucumber.runChild(Cucumber.java:38)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at cucumber.api.junit.Cucumber.run(Cucumber.java:100)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:86)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:538)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:760)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:460)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:206)
    at ✽.Given I access "wwww.google.com"(google.feature:4)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Sharing same selenium WebDriver between step definition files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31573676/sharing-same-selenium-webdriver-between-step-definition-files)

Comment: Have a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31573676/sharing-same-selenium-webdriver-between-step-definition-files

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happening because you are trying to create constructors in stepdefination file without putting picocontainer dependency. Its an dependency injection framework for cucumber

Either remove the constructor or add below dependency in POM

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/info.cukes/cucumber-picocontainer -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
    <artifactId>cucumber-picocontainer</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.5</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

You can remove  `<scope>test</scope>` tag if do not want to limit the transitivity of a dependency

Comment: It's not working, as I have already added the dependency..u can check my pom.xml which I have mentioned in question itself.for some reason I am unable to remove constructor.

Comment: No I haven't tried, I will try and let you know. Than you for the help..I have wasted full day in this .. really appreciated ur help...will let you know ...once I add scope