# Sharing the same Selenium WebDriver in several step definition files

Tags: javascript, selenium, cucumber, cucumberjs

My question is basically the same as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31573676) one. But I am writing my tests in JavaScript. I want to have several step definition files.
I tried creating a file with exported driver like this

```
var webdriver = require('selenium-webdriver');
var driver = new webdriver.Builder().forBrowser('chrome').build();

module.exports = driver;
```

I am importing this file in my step definition files with `const { driver } = require('test-driver')`
When I run the tests there are two browser windows opened insted of one.

What is the right way of sharing the same WebDriver between several step definition files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend using protractor(a wrapper for selenium) instead of webdriver directly as protractor has some neat built-in support for Javascript. Take a look here https://github.com/protractor-cucumber-framework/protractor-cucumber-framework

Then you can just import `browser` and use the driver across steps

Comment: Does not answer the question at all.