# How to put Before() & After() hooks in a hooks.js file in Selenium / JavaScript project?

Tags: javascript, selenium, cucumber, cucumberjs

In my Selenium JS / Cucumber framework, I have `Before()` & `After()` functions that create & tear down my webdriver.

I have put them in my `customSteps.js` file along with the other cucumber steps like so:

```
const { When, Then, Before, After } = require('@cucumber/cucumber')
const webdriver = require('selenium-webdriver')

let driver;

Before(() => {
    driver = new webdriver.Builder()
    .forBrowser('chrome')
    .build();
})

After(() => {
    driver.quit();
})

When('I visit {string}', {timeout: 2 * 5000},  async url => {
    await driver.get(url)
});

Then('the page header {string} is displayed', async expectedPageHeader => {});

When('I click the {string} button', async text => {});

Then('I am brought to the {string} page', async text => {});

When('the intro header text is {string}', async expectedPageHeader => {});

When('the intro subheader text is {string}', async expectedSubHeader => {});
```

Here are my `scripts` in `package.json`:

```
"scripts": {
    "test": "node_modules/.bin/cucumber-js -f @cucumber/pretty-formatter features/test.feature"
  }
```

My client has told me that only the `Given`, `When`, & `Then` steps should be in my `customSteps.js`, & that `Before()` & `After()` should be in `hooks.js` in a `support` folder.

I have tried to find Selenium JavaScript solutions online that do this, but I haven't been able to find one yet.

Can someone please tell me if my approach is the better approach, or should I be putting `Before()` & `After()` in a `hooks.js` file?

Also, some advice on how to do so would be appreciated, as those functions interact with my `driver` variable, which is needed in the `Given` step to visit the URL.

Finally, here's a picture of my current folder structure in case it's useful:

[image]

Comment: What does your npm test command look like?

Comment: Hi @Raju, I've updated my question with my `test` command

Answer (score 0):

If you are using cucumber runner, then you can add them into a separate file and pass it to the command.

cucumber.conf.js

```js
const { Before, After } = require('@cucumber/cucumber');

Before(() => {
    global.driver = new webdriver.Builder()
    .forBrowser('chrome')
    .build();
})

After(() => {
    driver.quit();
})
```

Then you should pass this as:

```json
"scripts": {
    "test": "node_modules/.bin/cucumber-js --require cucumber.conf.js -f @cucumber/pretty-formatter features/test.feature"
  }
```

This [repo](https://github.com/spnraju/demo-playwright-cucumberjs) has a similar example with the tool playwright.

Answer (score 0):

I would say it's more up to you how you decide to organise it.

But the reason why people are suggesting to have separately Given/When/Then/And and separately hooks is in first place one of best practices for writing StepDefs and then more about better readability and I would say also easier investigation in case you have some failure. Imagine if you have 40-50 StepDef classes and everywhere you have some Before/After hooks. It will become quite messy and not easy to follow what's happening before/after scenarios.

To the other question. If I understood it correctly you are asking how to reuse same instance of driver in more StepDef classes right? If yes this is the answer: [Sharing same selenium WebDriver between step definition files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31573676/sharing-same-selenium-webdriver-between-step-definition-files).